# Synonym request: [DAG] to [directed-acyclic-graphs]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

It looks like SO has both [dag](/questions/tagged/dag) (75 questions) and [directed-acyclic-graphs](/questions/tagged/directed-acyclic-graphs) (56 questions).  I'm partial to [directed-acyclic-graphs](/questions/tagged/directed-acyclic-graphs) personally, similar to what we did with [the terms dfs and bfs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110076/bfs-and-dfs-tags-synonyms-required).  So my proposal is, to be clear, to make this tag synonym.

[dag](/questions/tagged/dag) -> [directed-acyclic-graphs](/questions/tagged/directed-acyclic-graphs)

Though I have no strong objections to the other way, as long as we pick a tag and stick to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done.